# Cube won't appear in render

Tags: rendering

I have a simple cube with simple images as a material. I Uv unwrapped it and I made sure the camera was on for the show in render in the outliner. The first image shows the 3d view, and the second shows the render view. I don't have any nodes because I am in blender render. I also have a motion tracked image but no nodes either. [image: 3d view] [image: render view.]

Comment: Is your camera and lamp on a different layer?

Comment: Do you have any **lights** in the scene? Is the cube **enabled for rendering** (Camera icon on the outliner)?  Is the **camera** aimed at the object? (The image on top is not showing the camera view). Is there an other object **blocking** the camera? Are all the layers for the object included int the **render layers**? Do you have any strips on the VSE? If so disable **sequencer** in the post processsing section? Unfortunately we can't some of this issues with the images you posted. Please post more information or make the file available for inspection.

Comment: @cegaton What are Strips on the VSE? And how do I find out if it is in the render layers?

Comment: @cegaton Actually it was in the wrong layer. And thanks for helping!

Comment: Don't forget to confirm the answer.

Comment: @MasterHolbytla Um well how do you do that?

Comment: @Cegaton Write your answer as a answer not a question...

Comment: @MasterHolbytla you are confusing the answer section with comments. Comments are to ask for information or make remarks that will help us find an answer. Comments cannot be marked as accepted. Please read: http://blender.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment

Comment: Sorry! I meant as an answer not a comment!

Answer (score 2):

**Possible causes for a Blank render:**

No lights in scene.

Objects disabled for Render in outliner (camera icon).

Strips in VSE and Sequencer enabled.

Objects in different layer, or in a layer disabled in Render Layers.

Object blocked by other objects.

Active camera aiming in a different direction.

An object in the scene set as active camera.

*Any, some or all of the above*.